# How to publish React component without including react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am creating a [React](https://reactjs.org/) component and want to publish it.

I've put in the `package.json`:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
```

And expect that when building my module with webpack, my component would not yell this:

```
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react'
```

How can I compile a production component without including React?

I checked some famous ones :

[react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)
[react-toggle](https://github.com/aaronshaf/react-toggle)

And they list react only in peerDependecies (and in devDependecies, for testing and development purposes I guess)
If I add react to my devDeps and run `webpack -p` it compiles successfully but then I have `react` in my component bundle.

Here my [simple webpack config](https://gist.github.com/ciaoben/862321966666f3082ce60b3316ff190f)

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I added "external" option in webpack config (the gist is updated), with this is compiles correctly, it does not include React in the bundle, but when I import it in project with React to use it it gives me:

Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

soon as it finds `React.Component` of my component...

Answer (score 4):

You can set it as a `peerDependency` but also add it as a `devDependency` so you can install it locally. make sure it's as `external` in webpack config. That's about all you need

see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#object

```
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react'
    },
    'react-dom': {
      root: 'ReactDOM',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom'
    },
    'prop-types': {
      root: 'PropTypes',
      commonjs2: 'prop-types',
      commonjs: 'prop-types',
      amd: 'prop-types'
    }
  },

  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name]',
    library: "foobar",
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  }
```

when consuming:

```
"dependencies": { 
  "foobar": "1.0.0",
  "react": "~16.0.0",
  "react-dom": "~16.0.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have added externals options (you can see the updated gist in question), it compiles, keep out React as I wanted, but when I import it in a project with React and `import` it, it fails with "Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined" when it reads `React.Component`

Comment: the project that consumes it needs to have react installed so it can reoslve it. when you `npm install`, if not there, `peerDependenices` should whine and potentially break builds etc. additionally, you may have different build targets - such as UMD or CJS - make sure it's consistent. I've updated my answer to include a typical setup

Comment: PS cannot access gists, blocked behind a corporate firewall designed to prevent code leaking...

Comment: Npm does not warn me about wrong peerDeps in this case.. and in the same file I added my component I already import react and use it for other components.--